# structs and INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to add properties to my Model playing with my first MVVM app.
Now I want to add a place to save specific data in a clean way, so I used a struct.
But I am having issues to notify property changed, it does not have access to the method (An object reference is required for the non-static field)
Can someone explain to me why this happens and inform me on a strategy that fit my needs?

Thanks!

```
public ObservableCollection<UserControl> TimerBars
{
    get { return _TimerBars; }
    set
    {
        _TimerBars = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TimerBars");
    }
}

public struct FBarWidth
{
    private int _Stopped;
    public int Stopped
    {
        get { return _Stopped; }
        set
        {
            _Stopped = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name"); //ERROR: An object reference is required for the non-static field
        }
    }

    private int _Running;
    //And more variables
}


private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Comment: `FBarWidth` does not implement any INotifyPropertyChanged and `OnPropertyChanged` method is not defined in that struct scope. Can't you even see that? This is very basic C# understanding.

Comment: Well all of this is inside of a class that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged. And all that works on regular variables, but when I want to use a struct to define 'grouped' variables I cant get it working.
And yes I am quite new to this..

Comment: Based on your last comment; Look on my updated answer below.

Comment: You should avoid `struct` here. It is far from _"a clean way"_. And in the rare situation where yo do use structs, design them as immutable. And then INPC is irrelevant.

Comment: Why have you chosen to use a struct instead of a class for these objects? As Henk said, structs should be immutable, if they are not there are a lot of easy bugs can happen with your code when it makes copies of variables when you are not expecting them to.

Comment: You can refer it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43910487/inotifypropertychanged-in-c-sharp-structures?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnPropertyChanged` needs to be defined in the scope that you wish to update properties on.

For that to work you'll have to implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

And finally you have to provide the correct argument to the `OnPropertyChanged` method. In this example "Stopped"

```
public struct FBarWidth : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _Stopped;
    public int Stopped
    {
        get { return _Stopped; }
        set
        {
            _Stopped = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Stopped");
        }
    }

    private int _Running;
    //And more variables

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Edit: In your comment you mentioned that you've got a class sorounding the code you provided in your example.

That means you've nested a struct inside a class.
Just because you've nested your struct, doesn't mean it inherits properties and methods from the outer class. You still need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` inside your struct and define the `OnPropertyChanged` method inside it.

Comment: So I need to implements the interface for INotifyPropertyChanged twice, inside outside of the struct?

Comment: You need to implement the interface in the struct with the properties that needs to be updated. In your example above you haven't done that.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, so I'm assuming there is no better strategy here than to just duplicate the implementation where needed?

Comment: You could create a class that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface as well as the required method and field. Then inherit that class on all your viewmodels. Just remember that you can't use inheritance on structs.